# Count the number of binary strings of size n (ORDER DOES NOT MATTER)

Tags: combinatorics

If we have a 3-bit string,

There will be 4 possible ones:

$000$

$100, 010, 001$ - one group

$110, 101, 011$ - one group

$111$

I know it is always n+1, but why?

Comment: If the order doesn't matter, only the number of $1$ matters. How many $1$ can there be ?

Comment: So there are always $n$ spots for the 1 to go, and then we just include the string of all zeroes, which is $n+1$?

Comment: That's pretty much it.

Answer (score 1):

community wiki post so that the question can be closed

Since the order does not matter, two binary strings are distinguished only by the number of $1$'s that occur.  In a binary string of length $n$, the number of $1$'s can vary from $0$ to $n$.  Therefore, as you correctly concluded, the number of distinguishable strings is $n + 1$.